# Google Cloud dataflow and Cloud Functions error - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, apache-beam

I am triggering a Dataflow job from a Cloud Function in GCP.

**Code embedded in Cloud function**

```
import apache_beam as beam
import argparse

PROJECT = 'projectName'
BUCKET='bucketName'
SCHEMA = 'sr:INTEGER,abv:FLOAT,id:INTEGER,name:STRING,style:STRING,ounces:FLOAT'
DATAFLOW_JOB_NAME = 'jobName'

def discard_incomplete(data):
    """Filters out records that don't have an information."""
    return len(data['abv']) > 0 and len(data['id']) > 0 and len(data['name']) > 0 and len(data['style']) > 0


def convert_types(data):
    """Converts string values to their appropriate type."""
    data['abv'] = float(data['abv']) if 'abv' in data else None
    data['id'] = int(data['id']) if 'id' in data else None
    data['name'] = str(data['name']) if 'name' in data else None
    data['style'] = str(data['style']) if 'style' in data else None
    data['ounces'] = float(data['ounces']) if 'ounces' in data else None
    return data

def del_unwanted_cols(data):
    """Delete the unwanted columns"""
    del data['ibu']
    del data['brewery_id']
    return data

def execute(event, context):
    argv = [
      '--project={0}'.format(PROJECT),
      '--job_name={0}'.format(DATAFLOW_JOB_NAME),
      '--staging_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
      '--temp_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
      '--region=us-central1',
      '--runner=DataflowRunner'
   ]

    p = beam.Pipeline(argv=argv)
    input = 'gs://{0}/beers.csv'.format(BUCKET)

    (p | 'ReadData' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(input, skip_header_lines =1)
       | 'SplitData' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(','))
       | 'FormatToDict' >> beam.Map(lambda x: {"sr": x[0], "abv": x[1], "ibu": x[2], "id": x[3], "name": x[4], "style": x[5], "brewery_id": x[6], "ounces": x[7]}) 
       | 'DeleteIncompleteData' >> beam.Filter(discard_incomplete)
       | 'ChangeDataType' >> beam.Map(convert_types)
       | 'DeleteUnwantedData' >> beam.Map(del_unwanted_cols)
       | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
           '{0}:sandeep_beer_test.beer_data'.format(PROJECT),
           schema=SCHEMA,
           write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
    p.run()
```

Dataflow job does get triggered when Cloud function is executed but the job keeps failing. When I checked the job logs, I see this error message - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud.functions'`

**requirements.txt**

`apache-beam[gcp]`

The python code embedded in the Cloud Function works fine if I run it directly from cloud shell after installing apache-beam[gcp].

Pls share your inputs on how to get past the Dataflow error for missing module.

Thanks

Sandeep

Comment: Hello, Does your issue got resolved? If yes can you please post the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you're passing `--save_main_session`.

Comment: Hi robertwb, thanks for the response. I changed the cloud function code to remove --save_main_session as you suggested. Now I am seeing this error in the Dataflow job - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'. If I add the pipeline option again, it goes back to the previous error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud.functions'

Comment: Also, I have noticed that the cloud function keeps retriggering which results in a new dataflow job every few mins. I had set the trigger type as Cloud Storage and Event type as Finalize/create.

Comment: Hmm... It seems like google.cloud.functions has a different `__main__` and is calling your file `main`. Hopefully someone form cloud functions can chime in. In the meantime, you could try putting everything (including the imports and function definitions) into a function and call that (without `--sae_main_session`). That failing, put it in a separate python file and have your main file simply import and invoke a single `run()` method from there.

Comment: Hi @robertwb, I am not entirely clear on your suggestion since I am not super expert on python but here is what I tried next. I removed these 2 lines from my python code. Entry point is already set to "execute" in the cloud function setting. Unfortunately, I still see the same error in Dataflow job - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'` Code removed: `if __name__ == '__main__':
     execute()`

Comment: I think this is a quirk in how cloud function works. Move all your code to a new python file, say `my_beam_pipeline.py`, and put the code that was guarded by `if __name__ == '__main__'` into a function called `run()`. Now in your `main.py` write `import my_beam_pipeline; my_beam_pipeline.run()`.

Comment: Hi robert, thanks for the detailed steps. I created a new file and moved the entire code to the new file. In main.py, I added these 2 lines
`import my_pipeline
my_pipeline.execute()`

Entry pt. field in the cloud fn is mandatory which was earlier set to **execute**. Now I changed it to my_pipeline.execute. Also in the moved code, execute function which is creating the Beam pipeline had input params as event and context since this was a background function (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background). I removed those input params. Now the cloud fn deployment is failing :)

Comment: I guess I am missing the point that why the Dataflow job would fail with ModuleNotFound error when it is already kicked off by the cloud function. And cloud function is returning OK.

Comment: It looks like, based on the errors, that the issue is on the workers. The way it works is as follows: (1) CloudFunction invokes your main.py (2) your main.py builds a pipeline, which has references to various DoFns, etc. (3) these DoFns get pickled with respect to some module (e.g. __main__) and sent to workers and (4) the workers try to unpickle them (by importing the module they were in originally), and can't find them.